# Error Connecting Azure Database from Thingworx

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, thingworx, azure-postgresql

I am trying to connect my thingworx to azure postgres database. I have two azure accounts. When I am creating my postgresql database in one of the accounts and connecting then it is working fine.

But when I am trying to connect to the azure postgres database present in the second account , the connection is failing and I am getting the error as follows:

Unable to Invoke Service GetStudentData on Database_Functions : FATAL: Client from Azure Virtual Networks is not allowed to access the server. Please make sure your Virtual Network is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the postgresql is part of a [Virtual Network service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview) and a service endpoint tag was enabled.

To solve the problem disable the service endpoint and add the public IP to the Connection Security section.

Comment: Hi .. can you please tell in bit more detail how can I fix this.

Comment: Remove or disable the VNET rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-vnet-using-portal

Answer (score -1):

It seems a firewall rule problem, not at all related to TW itself.